# E(fx)clipse Hanging

Tags: eclipse, javafx

Ok folks, I posted a similar message the other day, but was unable to update it . A student of mine is trying to run JavaFX on her mac. We have updated JDK to JDK 11 and eclipse to 2018-09. We then install E(fx)clipse using the help, install new software. When it starts, it asks for home directory, and then hangs

The log is below

```
!SESSION 2018-11-30 14:41:07.845 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/izziharper/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/izziharper/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core 4 0 2018-11-30 14:41:08.591
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core [278]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
       org.apache.xmlrpc [68]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.24.2.v20180904-2231"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc [295]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.xmlrpc; bundle-version="3.0.0.v20100427-1100"
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is Java 11 which doesn't provide javax.xml.bind anymore, some Eclipse packages haven't yet been updated to deal with this properly, org.apache.xmlrpc being one of them. See [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511117) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539515)

Comment: Which version of e(fx)clipse have you installed? Minimum should be 3.4.1